# How to auto import products into store from supplier XML feed using Magmi?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import, xml, magmi

There is a company called techdata that provides a product URL, DTD's, and some other stuff. I'm a novice so I don't really know what any of that means but I have to somehow use that to import their products into my Magento Store. I have Magmi (the understandinge version) installed on my store because I know it's useful when importing a lot of products. Tech data provides a user manual but I don't understand most of it. You can take a look if u want, [here](https://tdcontent.techdata.com/Content/XMLGuide/index.htm). I know it's a lot to take in but any help is greatly appreciated. I posted this before but I didn't mention Magmi at all and most of the responses I got, I didn't really understand.

Comment: I am interested in the magmi version :) didn't know there was one not from sourceforge/github. For your question, I think you require at least basic PHP knowledge to transform the xml to a csv file. With that, you can use the magmi datapump API.

Comment: @Jas understande have updated there magmi tutorials to include stuff on the Magmi "Data Pump API" and the CLI interface. Might be useful